# EnvoyProxy upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers

Tags: https, devops, envoyproxy

I'm currently trying to set up envoy to take in a https request, and pass the request on as an http request to a separately running(via Docker) local endpoint(Envoy is also being run locally). Unfortunately, when I make the request via Postman I get the following error "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure". Any ideas on how this issue could be fixed?

The envoy.yaml file I'm using is the following:

```
# envoy
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: "listener"
    address: { socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8443 } }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_https
          http_filters: { name: envoy.filters.http.router }
          route_config:
            name: route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: host
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: cluster
                  timeout: 10s
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              - certificate_chain: { filename: "/etc/envoy/cert.crt" }
                private_key: { filename: "/etc/envoy/cert.key" }
            alpn_protocols: "h2,http/1.1"

  clusters:
  - name: cluster
    connect_timeout: 20s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: least_request
    health_checks:
      timeout: 5s
      interval: 2s
      unhealthy_threshold: 3
      healthy_threshold: 1
      http_health_check: { path: "/healthcheck" }
    circuit_breakers:
      thresholds:
        max_retries: 300
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster
      endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint: { address: { socket_address: { address: "0.0.0.0", port_value: 8080 } } }
```

If anything else is needed please let me know. Thanks in advance for the help/tips!

Answer (score 0):

Increase your cluster connect_timeout and try again. Maybe that will fix the problem.